# Convert date issue in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have dateformat issue where I need to convert the date from DB to different formats according to the login

Like I have 3 different format

DD/MM/YY,MM/DD/YY,DD/MMM/YY
I tried to convert using the following methods but no luck.

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(drtemp["StartDate"].ToString(),dateFormat,null,
   System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,out startDate);
orderDate =DateTime.ParseExact(drtemp["StartDate"].ToString(), dateFormat, null);
```

Any help is highly apprenticed
Thanks,
Magz

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
string formattedDate = ((DateTime)drtemp["StartDate"]).ToString(dateFormat);
```

See MSDN [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) reference

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
string date1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
string date2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yy");
```

In your case you could do

```
string formattedDate = drtemp["StartDate"].ToString("dd/MM/yy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or You could do this:

```
String.Format(dateFormat, (DateTime)drtemp["StartDate"])
```